# change img source with attr not working on ios5

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, ios5, attributes

I'm trying to change the source of an image and have t fade in when you click in another spot, and it's set up like so

```
$('.thumbs').bind('click', function() {
  $('#MyT').attr('class', 'wierd');
  $('#MyT').fadeIn(0);
});
```

it works well when I test it on Chrome, but when I upload it to iPad, it doesn't change the source. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well the first thing that is wrong is you are not changing the src in your example code you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the class value of the image won't change its `src`. If you wanted to change its source, you would do something like this:

```
$(".thumbs").on("click", function(){
  $("#MyT").attr("src", "image2.png").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

I'm assuming of course there is a `<img src="foo.png" id="MyT" />` on your page.